# Logic App limits and configuration - How to configure the Logic App action Run duration?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to configure the Logic App action Run duration? We are using a Webhook action in our workflow and we need it to wait for a certain duration for response(callback). If it doesn't get any response(callback) with in the configured time then the workflow should stop the Run or it should raise an exception which we can catch using scope action of Logic App. As per the documentation default Run duration is 90 days. We need it to change to some minutes. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are two actions "Delay" and "Terminate" which you can use with the conditions to achieve your scenario.

Comment: Thanks TusharJ. I did research on Delay and Terminate actions as you suggested. What happens if we get the response(callback) to webhook action with in the delay time configured? will it resume the workflow immediately as soon as webhook gets the response(callback)? or will it wait till the delay time completion and resumes the flow?.  We have more than 10 webhook actions in our workflow. If we depend on delay time completion then it takes more time to complete the run which won't meet our requirement.

Comment: Do we have any property in Webhook action which species the duration with in which it can terminate the logic app?

Comment: Currently timeout is not supported on webhook action (the action will wait for the callback until the run itself times out). Feel free to suggest this feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: As a workaround, you could use another webhook action followed by a terminate to kill the run. This hands control over the timeout/termination to an external service, so you would still need to configure it separately. Alternatively you can cancel active runs via management plane using the workflows/{name}/runs/{id}/cancel API).